# Usage of SuppressWarnings in java

Tags: java, file, warnings

I am working with Files in java and my IDE is VS-Code.The problem I am facing that it is showing the following as warnings alongwith a bunch of others-

```
Resource leak: 'sc' is never closed
Resource leak: 'scan' is never closed
```

where "sc" is defined as -

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and "scan" as -

```
File fobj=new File("Marks.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(fobj);
```

I am asking that Using `@SuppressWarnings("resources")` only blocks warning from Scanner object sc.Is there any way to block all of these open resources warnings which can be defined at the beginning of the Java file because I have to include @SuppressWarnings("resources") in every class I write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add suppressions to the containing class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resources")
class YourClass {
  // ...
}
```

and this will suppress *all* resources warnings in the class.

This isn't such a great idea, though, because it will also suppress warnings about resources you *do* want to close, like `scan`.

I would say you've got a deeper problem if you're worried about adding suppressions in all the places where the warnings occur, because this implies you've got warnings in a lot of places.

In terms of suppressing the warning just on the `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`: you should only be creating a single scanner on a stream, and, as such, you should only need to add the suppression in one place.

If you're creating multiple scanners on `System.in`, you may get unexpected results from them, consider each scanner may consume part of the input stream. A better approach is to construct one scanner (on a given stream), and pass it around.

For `Scanner scan`, a better approach than suppressing the warning would be just to close the stream, so there is no warning to suppress. Try-with-resources guarantees this:

```
File fobj=new File("Marks.txt");
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(fobj)) {
  // ... Do stuff with scan.
}
// And now it's guaranteed to be closed.
```

---

Note that you can use try-with-resources around `new Scanner(System.in)`, and it is guaranteed to be closed - but you shouldn't. Closing the `Scanner` closes the underlying stream - `System.in`.

You should only close streams that your code opened directly - your code didn't open `System.in`, the JVM did. `System.in` can't be reopened once closed, so you could accidentally break other parts of your code which assumed it would be open.

It's gross that you have to consider `System.in` and "other" streams separately - the "helpful" closing of child streams in `Scanner` (etc) is behavior that predates the try-with-resources syntax, so it's just something Java is stuck with.